# How to calculate moving average of distinct value count in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, moving-average

I have the following table:

```
date       user_city 
2000-01-01 amsterdam
2000-01-01 copenhagen
2000-01-01 amsterdam
2000-01-01 vienna
2000-01-01 prague
2000-01-02 vienna
2000-01-02 amsterdam
2000-01-02 tokio
2000-01-03 copenhagen
2000-01-03 london
2000-01-03 prague
2000-01-03 amsterdam
...
```

Now I would like to have a 7-day rolling average of the number of the `user_city` values without repetition (so in case of `2000-01-01` the daily number is only 4, as `amsterdam` is represented two times). What is the relevant SQL (MySQL) query to get the result?

Expected outcome (in case of a 3-day rolling average fitted to the example above):

```
window_start_date avg
2001-01-01        3.6666
2001-01-04        ?
2001-01-07        ?
```

I was able to produce the code in Python, it may helps understanding my aim:

```
df = original_table.groupby("date")["user_city"].nunique()
df = df.reset_index()
df["rolling_avg"] = df["user_city"].rolling(7).mean()
```

Comment: What rdbms are you using? The possible solutions will differ per rdbms. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Please add the expected outcome.

Comment: 7-day means for 2000-01-08 I look at the dates 2000-01-02 to 2000-01-08? Have you tried anything? Do you know windows functions in SQL? Else, do you know how to count in a correlated subquery? The average is the distinct city count divided by the days. All in all: what is the concrete question you are asking?

Answer (score 2):

After you edited your question, this will work for your three day rolling average.

First you can create a helper table, which will hold the start and end date of the windows you want to calculate the average over. You can do this by using a `recursive cte`. It is called `date_range` in the query below and will look like this:

| window_start_date | window_end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2000-01-01 | 2000-01-03 |
| 2000-01-04 | 2000-01-06 |
| 2000-01-07 | 2000-01-09 |
| ... | ... |

To get the correct amount of visits per day, you can use another cte counting the `DISTINCT` appearances of user_city and grouping by date. This is called `daily_counts` in the query below.

You can now `LEFT JOIN` the visits to the date range, using a conditional statement meaning the date of the visit is `BETWEEN` the window_start_date and window_end_date.

Lastly, `GROUP BY` the window_start_date and calculate the average number of visited cities.

```
WITH RECURSIVE date_range AS (
    SELECT '2000-01-01' as window_start_date, 
          '2000-01-01' + INTERVAL 2 day as window_end_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT window_start_date + INTERVAL 3 day, 
           window_end_date + INTERVAL 3 day
    FROM date_range
    WHERE window_start_date <= '2000-12-31'
), 

  daily_counts as (
    SELECT date, COUNT(DISTINCT user_city) AS daily_count
    FROM visits
    GROUP BY date
)

SELECT window_start_date, AVG(daily_count) AS avg
FROM date_range
LEFT JOIN daily_counts
  ON daily_counts.date BETWEEN window_start_date AND window_end_date
GROUP BY window_start_date
```

Added a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Htl5qDYF) which includes some more dates in the future. You can change the interval values in the date_range cte to get a 7 day rolling average.

Comment: Do you lack a GROUP BY in your WITH clause?

Comment: Whoops, need more coffee. Thank you!